# How can I make my ios app device-assignable?

Tags: ios, app-store, ios9

A new feature for iOS 9 is that organizations that do volume purchases can assign VPP licenses to a device, rather than to a particular user ID.

I received a request from a school to make one of my iOS apps device-assignable.
I have found lots of Apple press releases about this feature, and how users can find out on AppStore if an app is assignable, for example [this one](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205656) which suggests that my appStore listing should contain this text:

[image]

My AppStore listing does not contain this text, and I can't find any technical information about how to make my app assignable. According to [this forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cawug/UwMBZK2WVWg), I am not the only one.

So, does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Your client will assign apps to devices via their MDM or using Apple Confgurator 2. They need to request migration from redemption codes to managed distribution https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202863

Comment: @Paulw11: sadly it's not that simple. I have added a link to a page from Apple which explains what a device-assignable app should look like on the app store, and mine doesn't. And the school has been through this process with other apps, so they know the score from their end.

Comment: When did you last update this app?  I just checked one of my apps and it shows as "device assignable" and I didn't do anything special.  Also, do you have any pending updates under "agreements, tax and banking"?

Comment: The app was updated in June 2016, and iOS9 came out Sep15.  When I signed in to iTunes Connect, I was asked to accept a new agreement: maybe that will change the app's status in due course.

Comment: Maybe. Otherwise you may need to upload a new version